# UITableViewCell subview not displaying until redraw

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uilabel

This problem is driving me nuts.

I have a prototype UITableViewCell in my storyboard. It contains a bunch of subviews. One of the subviews, a UILabel, is misbehaving.

When the tableview loads and is displayed for the first time, all of the cells look fine. However, as the tableview scrolls down, eventually one of the cells shows up without the UILabel subview. It seems that it is always the first cell that is being recycled.

If I continue scrolling down the tableview, however, as soon as the misbehaving cell is clipped by the top of the tableview (when it begins to be scrolled off the top of the screen), the label appears just as it should.

So it seems that the label is there, and it receives the string that I assign to it in my cellForRowAtIndexPath method. It's just not getting drawn for some reason. I've tried inserting setNeedsDisplay messages in various places, but that hasn't helped.

What is also strange is that I'm using the very same UITableViewCell subclass with a duplicate view hierarchy in the storyboard in a different view controller, and there I don't have any trouble.

Anybody have some idea of how I can start to unravel this mystery?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you modifying the table cell or any of the subviews after you initialize it in the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: I am. I'm setting the text of the label, and doing some other things with other custom UIView subclasses. All of that works fine. It's just the UILabel that doesn't get drawn.

Comment: I'm having something really similar happen to me. On one particular cell, one label doesn't get drawn. If I break in code, the cell looks absolutely fine. If I do setNeedsDisplay, it shows up. Driving me nuts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like it's only a problem when you use a reusable cell, which means that the values on reusable cells may not be getting set until you're ready to scroll off.

Comment: I know that the value is being set *before* the cell appears on screen because all of the other subviews are properly configured. It's only the label that isn't drawn. When the label does show up, it's text value is correct, so that value seems to have been set along with all the others before the cell appeared on screen. Not sure what you're recommending as a solution…

Comment: The only other thing I could think of is that the label's view is not added as a subview, else you might want to post your cellForRowAtIndexPath code.